# Import only table data with excel to excel connection

Tags: excel, excel-2007

In the data connections options in excel, when I connect to a sheet in another workbook that contains only a Table with 100 rows, and import it as a table, it only shows the table that was in the sheet, but with a few extra empty rows and an extra empty column, is there a way for it to recognize only the table?

Comment: Seems a bit like a weird task. Why are you using "Connections" to import into Excel? Would it not be easier to either paste as link or to just copy?

Comment: @nbayly I was trying to "mimic" a protected view of a file, to create reports on demand over it